# Migrating ExtJS3 to ExtJS4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs3, extjs-mvc

I am newbie to ExtJS. As client requirement ExtJS3 code is there we need to convert it into ExtJS4.I am trying a lot but it is not displaying result.

Html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Search Window With Ext JS 4</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext-4.0.1/resources/css/ext-all.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext-4.0.1/ext-all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext-4.0.1/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="searchwindow.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="SearchRegionPan.js"></script>

<body>
<div id="panel" style="padding:10px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

ExtJS code:
searchwindow.js:

```
Ext.require(['*']);

 Ext.onReady(function(){

     Ext.QuickTips.init();

var SearchRegionPan = new SearchRegionPan();

//************************* SEARCH TAB **************************************
var searchTab = {
                    id          :   'searchTab',
                    border      :   false,
                    //autoHeight    :   true,
                    //title     :   searchTitle,
                    items       :   [SearchRegionPan,
                      {
                        xtype:'label',
                                    text:'',
                                    style:'padding:2px 1px 0 40px;font-weight: bold;color: red;text-align: center;',
                                    itemId  :   'totallabel'
                                    }],
                    title       :   'Search'
                };

//*************************** SCHOOL INFO TAB **********************************
var schoolInfo = {
                    id          :   'schoolInfo',
                    autoScroll  :   true,
                    border      :   false,
                    //autoHeight    :   true,
                    title       :   'School Info'
                };

//************************ QUICK SEARCH TAB ***************************************
var quickSearchMainTab = {
                    layout      :   'column',
                    //columnWidth:  0.5,
                    xtype       :   'panel',
                    border      :   false,
                    //autoHeight    :   true,
                    id          :   'quickpanelID',         
                    title       :   'Quick Search',     
                    bodyStyle   :   'background:#f7fbfc;'
                };


//***************************** LAYERS ****************************************
var layerss = {
                    id          :   "tree",
                    //title     :   layersTitle,
                    title       :   'Layers',
                    xtype       :   "treepanel",
                    height      :   290,    
                    //showWmsLegend:    true,
                    //model     :   model
                    enableDD    :   true
              }; 

//****************************** TABS IN SEARCH MAIN TAB ********************************
var tabs = {
                    margins         :   '3 3 3 0',
                    activeTab       :   0,
                    style           :   'background:none; padding-top:10px',
                    plain           :   true,
                    xtype           :   'tabpanel',
                    id      :'tabs',                    frame           :   false,
                    border          :   false,
                    //autoHeight        :   true,
                    deferredRender  :   false,
                    items           :   [searchTab, schoolInfo, quickSearchMainTab, layerss]
            };

// ***************************** SEARCH MAIN TAB ******************************************
var searchMainTab = {
                    id              :   'searchMainTab',
                    layout          :   'fit',
                    border          :   false,
                    //title         :   searchInfoTitle,
                    title           :   'Search Info',
                    items           :   [tabs]
                    //autoHeight    :   true
                    //iconCls           :   's_ico'             
                }; 

 //********************************** searchTabs USED IN SEARCH WINDOW *******************************   
searchTabs = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel',{
                    margin          :   '3 3 3 0',
                    activeTab       :   0,
                    style           :   'background:none',
                    plain           :   true,
                    id              :   'searchTabs',
                    //autoHeight        :   true,
                    width           :   350,
                    //baseCls           :   'srcTab',
                    style           :   'padding-top:10px',
                    frame           :   false,
                    items           :   [searchMainTab],
                    border          :   false   
                  });

// *********************************** SEARCH WINDOW *************************************
searchWin = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{
                    title           :   '<p style="font:1px tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;color:white"></p>',
                    //width         :   360,
                    width           :   400,
                    height          :   380,
                    autoHeight      :   true,
                    x               :   100,   //to display search window 100px from left
                    y               :   100,   //to display search window 100px from top
                    draggable       :   true,
                    autoScroll      :   false,
                    plain           :   true,
                    id              :   'searchMainWindow',
                    layout          :   'fit',
                    border          :   true,
                    //baseCls           :   'searchWin',
                    //animateTarget :   'searInfo',
                    resizable       :   false,
                    shadow          :   false,
                    frame           :   false,
                    closeAction     :   'hide',
                    items           :   [searchTabs],
                    renderTo        :   panel   //used to render to html page
                    });
                    searchWin.show();
    });    


SearchRegionPan.js:

Ext.require('*');

//*************** SEARCH REGION PAN USED IN SEARCH TAB ***************************
SearchRegionPan = Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{
                    id          :   'searchRegionPan',
                    border      :   false,          
                    style       :   'padding:5px 10px 0 10px ',
                    items       :   [RegionCityDistForm],
                    frame       :   false
                });

//************** REGIONCITYDISTFORM USED IN SEARCH TAB **********************************
var RegionCityDistForm = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel',{
                    extend          :   'Ext.panel.Panel',
                    id              :   'regioncitydistform',
                    frame           :   true,
                    border          :   true,
                    height          :   100,
                    padding         :   '10px 20px 10px 10px',
                    width           :   '100%',
                    layout          :   'anchor',
                    fieldDefaults   :   {
                        labelWidth  :   140
                    },
                    items           :   [Region,City,District]
            });

//*************************** REGION DECLARATION *********************************
var Region  =   Ext.create('Ext.form.TextField',{
                    fieldLabel      :   'Region',
                    selectOnFocus   :   true,
                    width           :   330,
                    allowBlank      :   false,
                    editable        :   true,
                    emptyText       :   'Select a Region...',
                    triggerAction   :   'all',
                    typeAhead       :   true
            });

//**************************** CITY DECLARATION *********************************
var City    =   Ext.create('Ext.form.TextField',{
                    fieldLabel      :   'City',
                    selectOnFocus   :   true,
                    width           :   330,
                    allowBlank      :   false,
                    editable        :   true,
                    emptyText       :   'Select a City...',
                    triggerAction   :   'all',
                    typeAhead       :   true
            });

//************************* DISTRICT DECLARATION ************************************
var District    =   Ext.create('Ext.form.TextField',{
                    fieldLabel      :   'District',
                    selectOnFocus   :   true,
                    width           :   330,
                    allowBlank      :   false,
                    editable        :   true,
                    emptyText       :   'Select a District...',
                    triggerAction   :   'all',
                    typeAhead       :   true
            });
```

As per my Knowledge i am expecting that new keyowrd is not working in ExtJS4 version.If anyone knows please let me know.

Thanks in Advance,
Ramu

Comment: I have doubt, If you have chat permission [look this](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7451/extjs-3-x-4-x-java-script-framework)

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at this:
http://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-js-3-to-4-migration/

There is a compatibility layer, that hopefully will get your app up and running. Once you have something to look at, it will be easier to address your migration issues.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I would start off with the compatibility layer and also check out the migration [screencasts](http://vimeo.com/23027769) for pointers on debugging compatibility issues.  In general the `new` keyword still works OK.  `Ext.create()` is preferred under the new class system, but it seems like you are mostly doing that.  If the page is not rendering, then you'll have to do a little debugging to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: thanks a lot.But here i am trying to add dynamic js files by creating objects using new keyword.Is this will work with ExtJS4 or else we need to use Loader?